# What is the syntax for non-parallel for loops or running series of subsets for Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, pandas-groupby

I have an algorithm that I want to run for every subset of this dataframe. The for loop that I was able to do still run all groups in parallel. I want to run it one by one.

[image]

Sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'STORE': ['Store_1', 'Store_1', 'Store_1', 'Store_2', 'Store_2', 'Store_2'],
              'ITEM': ['oranges', 'oranges', 'oranges', 'oranges', 'oranges', 'oranges'],
               'AVAILABLE': [5, 5, 5, 13, 13, 13],
              'USER': ['1', '2', '3', '1', '5', '4'],
               'NEED': [1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3],
               'GROUP': [1,1, 1, 2, 2, 2], })
df
```

The idea I have is to start with getting the maximum number of group:

```
total_groups = df["GROUP"].max()

run = 0
while run != total groups
   # algorithm here
```

I'm not sure what the syntax is for non-parallel for loop or how to even begin it. In reality I have several groups. Can someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: You have to go out of your way to have anything running in parallel in python

Comment: you mean non parallel?

Comment: I mean that `for` loops do not run in parallel

Comment: You need `groupby`, which isn't to do with "parallel" - you just need to group your data. What you're terming parallel is really just an operation applying to a whole column at once

Comment: Can you share how I can group by every group and run them one by one? The problem I have is after the first group runs, some rows for the second group needs to be updated. In this dataframe for example that I shared, after Group 1 runs - index 3 will have an updated Need because it's the same store from Group 1. Then it will run.